# How to execute query without waiting for results in ms sql?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure-automation

My objective is to launch a query on a remote server that delete some rows from a table.
The problem is that the query takes a lot of time to complete and I don't want the client to wait for its completion (also because we pay for each second the process works, it's an Azure automation PowerShell job).
Is there a way to do that?
[Edit] My sql server is an Azure SQL server, then I cannot use Agent SQL. I just want to know if it exists a method to run a query without waiting its results.. [/Edit]

Comment: You can use service broker to run procedures asynchronously, old but still valid post here: http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/

Comment: if you can run it from powershell, you can use Jobs, or RunSpaces

Comment: Does the user need to start the delete process or is it an unattended process?

Comment: It's unattended.  Just a delete query to clean old data

Answer (score 1):

You can use .Net API [SqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b6f9k7k(v=vs.110).aspx), that would allow to submit the query execution request asynchronously and continue with other tasks. Callback will be executed when query results are available, but you can just put an empty implementation if you are not interested in the actual results.

Comment: Is it possibile to do it in a ps script in azure Automation?

Comment: Yes. I do not have an example of a runbook that would use BeginExecuteNonQuery handy, but here is the example that uses synchronous version - ExecuteNonQuery: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Azure-Automation-Your-SQL-30f8736b#content. You can just follow the example and replace **ExecuteNonQuery** with **BeginExecuteNonQuery** and pass appropriate parameters. The code line right after your call of **BeginExecuteNonQuery** - will execute without waiting for the results of the query.

Answer (score -1):

On SQL Server.

1. Create Stored procedure to delete rows from the table.
2. Create linked Server on on the remote server with RPC enabled(TRUE).

Use this link for assistance https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782(v=sql.105).aspx

3. To delete records execute the Stored Procedure

   ```
   EXEC [RemoteServer] .DatabaseName.DatabaseOwner.StoredProcedureName
   ```

For detailed information about Asynchronous procedure execution. Visit
http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/

Thanks

Comment: Please explain how this is going to behave in asynchronous a way and what's different from executing the sproc on local system.